# ExtJS4 date deserialization in a store

Tags: extjs4, deserialization

My Java backend sends the date serialized as a long (milliseconds) in a JSON response. How can I deserialize the date in a store?

When the definition is just `'myDate'`, it defaults to string deserialization and is shown in milliseconds.

With the definition `{name: 'myDate', type: 'date'}`, myDate will be shown as *`undefined`* in firebug.

The same happens with `{name: 'myDate', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'l'}` (also for `'L'`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docs for [dateFormat](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-dateFormat) config say:

> A format string for the Ext.Date.parse function, or "timestamp" if the
>   value provided by the Reader is a UNIX timestamp, or **"time"** if the
>   value provided by the Reader **is a javascript millisecond timestamp**

Try the following:

```
{name: 'myDate', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'time'}
```